# Perform check on two columns, Copy column by column another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a method for checking particular column in range for blanks. Then if column is not blank I would like to copy all values from that row to another Worksheet.

Now I am completely stuck. Anybody can give some hint how to proceed with the loop in order to achieve result as on the screenshot below?

In example below I need to copy:

1. From Column B rows 19, 20, 22 to another sheet Column A (starting from A8)
2. From Column C rows 19, 20, 22 to another sheet Column B (starting from B8)
3. From Column E rows 20, 22 to another sheet Column C (starting from C9)
4. From Column F rows 20, 22 to another sheet Column D (starting from D9)
5. From Column G rows 20, 22 to another sheet Column E (starting from E9)

In my current code If statement basically does not work as an output I get all rows to Debug window.

Here is the code (method):

```
Sub CopyTimeScheduleMethod(SearchWordOne As String, SearchWordTwo As String, RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)

    Dim FirstWord, SecondWord
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
            
    Set FirstWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(SearchWordOne, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set SecondWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(SearchWordTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    Set rng = OperatingWorksheet.Range(OperatingWorksheet.Cells(FirstWord.row + 2, FirstWord.Column), _
OperatingWorksheet.Cells(SecondWord.row - 3, FirstWord.Column))
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("A8:G90").ClearContents

    For Each row In rng.Rows
      For Each cell In row.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=21).Value) And _
        Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value) Then
            Debug.Print cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
        End If
      Next cell
    Next row

End Sub
```

As an output I get:

```
1.1
1.1.2.1
```

How I can build my If statement to have `1 Task` as well for first column and second (B and C) column but exclude it from other Columns (E, F and G)?

Here is the range on `rng.Copy` (From here I need to copy):

[image]

Here is how it should look like on another Worksheet:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

This is now working as it should, but there is still a problem with first "Header" row. How to catch it? One option is of course to just remove "OPT" from Source Worksheet, from Column V.

```
Sub CopyTimeScheduleMethod(SearchWordOne As String, SearchWordTwo As String, RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)

    Dim FirstWord, SecondWord
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim x
            
    Set FirstWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(SearchWordOne, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set SecondWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(SearchWordTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    Set rng = OperatingWorksheet.Range(OperatingWorksheet.Cells(FirstWord.row + 2, FirstWord.Column), _
    OperatingWorksheet.Cells(SecondWord.row - 3, FirstWord.Column))
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("A8:G90").ClearContents
    
    x = 8

    For Each row In rng.Rows
      For Each cell In row.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=21).Value) And _
        Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Value) Then
            Debug.Print cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("A" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("B" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("C" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=4).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("D" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=5).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("E" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=6).Value
             
             x = x + 1
             
        End If
      Next cell
    Next row

End Sub
```

Basically what is still left to solve is how to make If statement where:

1. cell in column C is not empty
2. cell in column V is not empty or not "OPT"

   ```
   If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=21).Value) And _
   cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=21).Value <> "OPT" And _
   Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Value) Then
   ```

Comment: In your if-clause, I see `A and B or C`, does this mean `(A and B) or C` or `A and (B or C)`?

Comment: @Dominique I have edited my question. I have managed to get my code a little bit further but there are still issues with the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution:

```
Sub CopyTimeScheduleMethod(SearchWordOne As String, SearchWordTwo As String, RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)

    Dim FirstWord, SecondWord
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim x As Integer
            
    Set FirstWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(SearchWordOne, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set SecondWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(SearchWordTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    Set rng = OperatingWorksheet.Range(OperatingWorksheet.Cells(FirstWord.row + 2, FirstWord.Column), _
    OperatingWorksheet.Cells(SecondWord.row - 3, FirstWord.Column))
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("A8:G90").ClearContents
    
    x = 8

    For Each row In rng.Rows
      For Each cell In row.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Value) And _
        (cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=21).Value = "OPT" Or _
        IsEmpty(cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=21).Value)) Then
            'Debug.Print cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("A" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("B" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("C" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=4).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("D" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=5).Value
             
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("E" & x).Value _
             = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=6).Value
             
             x = x + 1
             
        End If
      Next cell
    Next row

End Sub
```